# How to initialize a const int 2-dimension vector in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, vector, constants

How to initialize a const int 2-dimension vector:

```
Const int vector < vector < int > >  v ? 

v = {1 , 1 ; 1, 0}  ?
```

it does not work .

Comment: I don't think this does what you think it does. A [`const` vector](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/const.html#fqa-18.1) is a vector that you cannot modify. It does not make the objects inside it `const`.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this ([only in C++11](http://ideone.com/ayLiT)):

```
const vector<vector<int>>  v{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
```

Also note that you don't need to write `> >`. As this issue has been fixed in C++11, `>>` would work. It wouldn't be interpreted as right-shift operator (as was the case with C++03).

Comment: Well that certainly won't compile with a shift right in there.

Answer (score 5):

If your compiler supports the initialisation-list feature (is that what it's called?) of C++11, you can do this:

```
const vector<vector<int>> v {
    { 1, 2, 3 },
    { 4, 5, 6 }
};
```

Note that you won't be able to add any elements to the first dimension (but you can add elements to the second), e.g.

```
v.push_back(vector<int> { 8, 9, 10 }); // BAD
v[0].push_back(4); // OK
```

If you wanted the second dimension to be non-modifiable, you'd do

```
vector<const vector<int>> {
    { 1, 2, 3 },
    { 4, 5, 6 }
};
```

Then

```
v.push_back(const vector<int> { 8, 9, 10 }); // OK
v[0].push_back(4); // BAD
```

OR if you want the elements themselves to be `const`, you would do

```
vector<vector<const int>> {
    { 1, 2, 3 },
    { 4, 5, 6 }
};
```

Then

```
v.push_back(vector<const int> { 8, 9, 10 }); // OK
v[0].push_back(4); // OK
v[0][0] = 2; // BAD
```

You probably want to modify it at runtime, so it's probably good to remove the `const` altogether.

Answer (score 0):

```
using namespace std;

int main(void){

    const vector< vector<int> > v(10, vector<int>(10,1));

    return 0;

}
```

Initialises a 10x10 array to 1